# Mine to 2 Separate Wallets on a Single 6 Card Rig

Tags: mining, wallets

I am attempting to set up 5 rigs. I would like each rig on Linux. I am attempting to, in some way, have the mining power split between 2 wallets on each rig. I'm not sure how, but I would like to use a portion of the processing power or 2 of the 6 cards in each rig to mine to a separate wallet and use the remaining cards to mine to a primary wallet. Would you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Most, if not all, mining programs allow you to specify which GPUs you use for mining. Thus, you can launch two instances of your miner software and specify GPUs 1 and 2 with coinbase A and GPUs 3-6 to mine to coinbase B (or whatever specific distribution you want).

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a smart contract and set that as the mining account. The contract can split funds between your accounts.

You can use this smart contract deploy, add partners and mine to it. Make sure the reward (if sent by a pool) is sent with enough gas to be able to split the funds.

Check this smart contract
https://github.com/cleanunicorn/smart-split

Example of transaction that splits funds to defined partners
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x515b444d29ca85e845dba72d4d478ffad16db745b23b1c336ec10764853a9b83

Answer (score 0):

Gminer currently supports charging a maintenance fee. This will **simultaneously mine to two separate wallets** (even across pools). All you need to do is list one wallet using the default method and the second wallet as a maintenance wallet. You can choose an even (after dev-fee) split by specifying a 50% maintenance fee.

---

Miner supports charging of maintenance fee (maintenance fee charging after charging developers fee), example:
`miner --algo ethash --server eth.2miners.com:2020 --user 0x5218597d48333d4a70cce91e810007b37e2937b5.worker1 --maintenance_server eth.2miners.com:2020 --maintenance_user 0x270686d8A5c33Ba2E584EF8e94128A07B57BcB2A --maintenance_fee 20`

- `eth.2miners.com:2020` - maintenance fee pool
- `0x270686d8A5c33Ba2E584EF8e94128A07B57BcB2A` - maintenance fee wallet
- `20` - maintenance fee percent

---

Source: [GMiner Github release notes](https://Miner%20supports%20charging%20of%20maintenance%20fee%20(maintenance%20fee%20charging%20after%20charging%20developers%20fee),%20example:%20miner%20--algo%20ethash%20--server%20eth.2miners.com:2020%20--user%200x5218597d48333d4a70cce91e810007b37e2937b5.worker1%20--maintenance_server%20eth.2miners.com:2020%20--maintenance_user%200x270686d8A5c33Ba2E584EF8e94128A07B57BcB2A%20--maintenance_fee%2020%20eth.2miners.com:2020%20-%20maintenance%20fee%20pool%200x270686d8A5c33Ba2E584EF8e94128A07B57BcB2A%20-%20maintenance%20fee%20wallet%2020%20-%20maintenance%20fee%20percent)